# How do I scroll in a native Android app using Appium Java?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, appium, mobile-automation

How do I automate scrolling in a native Android application? For example, on a 'terms and conditions' page. I am using Appium with selenium webdriver.

Comment: Anirban - Can you accept answer if it helps you. So this question will no longer be in active queue.

Answer (score 1):

The snippet below is not for any particular mobile screen size. It is fetching the actual screen size each time.

```
    public void scroller() throws IOException 
{
      Dimension dimensions = ad.manage().window().getSize();
      System.out.println("Size of Window= " +dimensions);
      int scrollStart = (int) (dimensions.getHeight() * 0.5);
      System.out.println("Size of scrollStart= " +scrollStart);
      int scrollEnd = (int) (dimensions.getHeight() * 0.2);
      System.out.println("Size of cscrollEnd= " + scrollEnd);             
      driver.swipe(0,scrollStart,0,scrollEnd,1000);           
      System.out.println("Screen Swiped " );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using python-client of appium:

```
def _find_by_scroll(self, item_name):

    item = self.driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator(
        'new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).getChildByText(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView"), "'
        + item_name + '")')
    item.click()
```